# how to add map entries to a synchronized/non synchronized map from a synchronized map java

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

How to add map entries to a synchronized/non synchronized map from a synchronized map, using addAll() - Java?

```
 Map<String,String> h = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String,String>());
 Map<String,String> g = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String,String>());
// or even better - Map<String,String> = new HashMap<String,String>();
 h.put("kkk","eee");
 Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> s = h.entrySet();
 Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> ss = g.entrySet();
 ss.addAll(s); //causes unsupportedoperationexception for both the synchronized version
                // of map g and the unsynchronized, even if this operation is placed 
                  // in a synchronized block (synchronized(h){}, and synchronized(g){})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashMap`'s `EntrySet` does not support `addAll`, full stop.  The synchronization has nothing to do with it.  To copy everything from h to g just do `g.putAll(h);`.

The way `equals()` is specified for `Map.Entry<K,V>` means the `add` and `addAll` operations wouldn't behave properly for the entrySet.  Map.Entry says that two entries are equal if both their Key and Value match.  So you ought to be able to add ["Foo", "Baz"] to an entrySet that already contains ["Foo","Bar"] since they're not the same according to `equals`.  Of course we know this is impossible, the entrySet could not contain both of those, the new mapping for Foo would have to replace the old one.  So the methods are simply not supported.